# Joomla 3.0 Hello World Program Will Not Display

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

Long story short: I tried copying a Hello World plugin for Joomla designed to put "Hello World" on every article, it installed properly, yet doesn't work at all.

**helloworld.php:**

```
<?php
// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

class plgContentHelloworld extends JPlugin
{
   public function onContentAfterTitle($context, &$article, &$params, $limitstart)
    {
            return "<p>Hello World!</p>";
    }
}

?>
```

**helloworld.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension version="2.5" type="plugin" group="content">
    <name>plg_content_helloworld</name>
    <author>Brad Markle</author>
    <creationDate>June 18th, 2012</creationDate>
    <copyright>InMotion Hosting</copyright>
    <license>GNU General Public License</license>
    <authorEmail>bradm@inmotionhosting.com</authorEmail>
    <authorUrl>http://www.inmotionhosting.com</authorUrl>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <description>Simple Hello World Plugin that prints "Hello World" at the beginning of every article.</description>
    <files>
            <filename plugin="helloworld">helloworld.php</filename>
            <filename>index.html</filename>
    </files>
</extension>
```

I already made sure that I enabled the plugin and disabled the "Show Intro Text" on all the articles.

Comment: Are you getting any specific error messages that might help us?

Comment: Do you have error reporting set to "development"? Alos, to debug you could test to see if the event is being triggered and responded to by echoing a string in the plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-25/create-plugin/changing-text-using-oncontentprepare). A Content Plugin that replaces all "A" with "a". 
That should help you a lot (as me in the past).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!  I tried this plugin and it worked fine, but the other plugin remains a mystery to me, so at least I know plugins work!

Comment: maybe you want to tell us what you want to do. Just putting something to each article is much easier without a plugin. Maybe the article override is enough for you. most things you can do without coding own plugins. And i think that `afterDisplayTitle` only works if you set "hide introtextes" in blog manager or article (but dont remember 100%).